# Url redirection inside a modal window

Tags: javascript, jsp, redirect, modal-dialog

My webapp can be run "by itself" or opened in a modal window by another webapp...

When the user closes the window I must clean some data so I catch the event of closing the window and I redirect to a certain action like this:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0) || (window.event.clientX < -80) || window.event.altKey == true) { // close button or ALT+F4
                window.location.assign('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/borraSemaforo.do');
            }
        };
    </script>
```

This works when the webapp is runing in a non-modal window, but not inside a modal window.

I have no control over the application that opens mine in a modal window so I can not make any change to the way the window is opened...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases where your application loads in a modal window:

One way is:

You can create an hidden iframe in the window in your onbeforeunload event handler.
In the iframe put the url of the action.

Another way -

Create a small modal window pointing to the url path. In the response of that url path send a small javascript to just close the modal window.

Code for opening an iframe - basic js

```
    var i = document.createElement('iframe');
            i.style.display = "none";
            var d = new Date();
            i.id = d.getTime();
    i.onload = function(){
/*Task complete*/
 alert('frame loaded')}
            i.name = "exp" + d.getTime();
            i.src = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '<path>';
            document.body.appendChild(i);
```

Comment: But what would happen when the app is running non-modal?

Comment: Two tricks then....
1. Either pass a reference from the url query params or through a cookie that the app is currently running in a modal window
2. Just do the same thing for non-modal launches of the application too..

Comment: Ok, could you write a piece of code with the 1st trick with the iframe thing? I can't seem to figure how to accomplish that...

Comment: Another trick -If you have control over the page which opens the modal window, then you can execute your code there too.